# Compact Hausdorff space with closed set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $f$ from $X$ to $X$ a one-to-one continuous function. Show that there exist a nonempty closed subset $A$ of $X$ such that $f[A] = A$.

It is obvious that $f$ is closed So, it is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1-1 is not needed, in fact. Define $A_0 = X$, $A_{n+1} = f[A_n]$ for $n \ge 0$. Show that all $A_n$ are compact subsets of $X$, and $A_{n+1} \subseteq A_n$ for all $n$.

Then show $A = \cap_n A_n$ is as required (non-emptyness follows from standard compactness arguments), closedness is clear.

Comment: You are right. However, one-to-one is necessary

Comment: @Gob do you have a counterexample? The proof is easier with 1-1